# through html and css resizing background image for ie8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

How should i sort out a solution for re sizing background image issue in Internet Explorer 7/ 8 ? I tried in search engines for this more, I couldn't get any valuable results. Give me some solution for solving this issue.

Comment: "Give me some solution for solving this issue" probably won't go down too well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various methods. One, you could use CSS 'hacks' to achieve different results. For example.

```
.myElement {
    background-image: url('myimage-600px.png'); /* Modern browsers */
    background-image: url('myimage-400px.png')\9; /* Internet explorer 8 and lower */
    *background-image: url('myimage-200px.png'); /* Internet explorer 7 and lower */
}
```

Alternatively, you could use media queries, and include the css3-mediaqueries-js for IE support. [**Here**](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) is the JavaScript file.

To perform a media query, you can write it using a method like this.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .myElement {
        background-image: url('myimage-800px.png');
    }
}
```